# RestTemplate GET request with custom headers and parameters resulted in 400 (null)

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate

I am writing a client for my REST service using Spring. When I try to consume the service I get 400 response error. It's Bad Request so there must be something wrong with my headers or parameters but I can't figure out what in particular.

My REST controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/menu/{count}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showMenu(@RequestHeader(required = false) String locale, @RequestParam boolean includeVegan,
                           @RequestParam boolean includeMeat, @RequestParam boolean includeGlutenFree,
                           @PathVariable(value = "count") int count) {

        List<Meal> filteredMeals = new ArrayList<>();

        if (count == 0) count = menuService.getMeals().size();

        // Tworzenie przefiltrowanego menu.
        for (Meal meal : menuService.getMeals()) {
            if (count <= 0) break;
            if (meal.isVegan() && includeVegan) filteredMeals.add(meal);
            if (!meal.isVegan() && includeMeat) filteredMeals.add(meal);
            if (meal.isGlutenFree() && includeGlutenFree) filteredMeals.add(meal);
            count--;
        }

        // Tworzenie nazw pozycji posiłków w wybranym języku.
        List<String> menu = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Meal meal : filteredMeals) {
            if (locale == null) {
                // BOTH LANGUAGES
                menu.add(meal.toString(true));
                menu.add(meal.toString(false));
            } else if (locale.equals("pl-PL")) {
                // POLISH LANG
                menu.add(meal.toString(true));
            } else if (locale.equals("en-US")) {
                // ENGLISH LANG
                menu.add(meal.toString(false));
            }
        }

        return menu.toString();
    }
```

Client fetch method:

```
private void fetchMenu() {

        String locale = languageComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        boolean includeVegan = includeVeganCheckBox.isSelected();
        boolean includeMeat = includeMeatCheckBox.isSelected();
        boolean includeGlutenFree = includeGlutenFreeCheckBox.isSelected();
        int limit = (int) limitSpinner.getValue();

        System.out.println("DEBUG: locale: " + locale + ", vegan " + includeVegan + ", meat: " + includeMeat +
                ", glutenFree: " + includeGlutenFree + ", limit: " + limit);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("locale", locale);

        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);

        Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.put("includeVegan", includeVegan);
        parameters.put("includeMeat", includeMeat);
        parameters.put("includeGlutenFree", includeGlutenFree);

        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange(
                "http://localhost:8080/menu/" + limit,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                entity,
                String.class,
                parameters
        );

        menu.setText(response.getBody());
    }
```

Console when calling `fetchMenu()`

```
DEBUG: locale: pl-PL, vegan false, meat: true, glutenFree: false, limit: 0
16:57:37.082 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created GET request for "http://localhost:8080/menu/0"
16:57:37.082 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Setting request Accept header to [text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*]
16:57:37.097 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8080/menu/0" resulted in 400 (null); invoking error handler
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:700)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:653)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:540)
    at ait.lab3.SwingClient.fetchMenu(SwingClient.java:101)
    at ait.lab3.SwingClient.access$000(SwingClient.java:16)
    at ait.lab3.SwingClient$5.actionPerformed(SwingClient.java:65)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Service method response is String as you can see. This is for my college classes so I need to use @RequestHeader and @PathVariable. I think something might be wrong with my headers/parameters or with path variable `count` which in `fetchMenu()` method is represented as `limit`.

I have no idea what might be wrong with my code. Please developers, help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make the following change in the fetchMenu() method.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = template.exchange(
                    "http://localhost:8080/menu/" + limit +"?includeVegan={includeVegan}&includeMeat={includeMeat}&includeGlutenFree={includeGlutenFree}",
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    entity,
                    String.class,
                    parameters
            );
```

Comment: So what does uriParameters parameter in exchange() method do? Shouldn't it add parameters to my URI?

Comment: It won't add any new params, it will replace the tokens with the values corresponding to the keys in uriParameters map.